# Error: Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "User"

Tags: python, discord.py

I keep getting the error even after copying the same exact code as the tutorial I'm following.

> Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "User"

Here is the code:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Cog(commands.Cog):

    @commands.command(aliases=["l", "lvl", "rank", "r"])
    async def level(self, ctx, user: discord.User=None):
        if user is None:
            user=ctx.author
        elif user is not None:
            user=user
```

Here is the full code I put into the cog:
https://pastebin.com/rKUq9U8D.

I'm not really sure what I tried to do as I'm new to coding and am just following a discord.py tutorial on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

You've said `user` must be a `discord.User`, but `None` is not a `User`, so it's not an appropriate default argument. If you want to allow `None` as type for `user`, you need to specify that it's allowed:

```
async def level(self, ctx, user: discord.User | None = None):

# or

async def level(self, ctx, user: typing.Union[discord.User, None] = None):
```

This is also only a warning unless you've configured your environment to treat type warnings as errors.

Comment: This works but it then tells me how "name" is not a known member of "None" and how "id" is not a known member of "None".

Comment: @bigman Those are different errors unrelated to the code you've posted here.